# Feeling "lost" when I am on Linux

Tags: xubuntu

I don't know if this question really is on-topic for this website. But if I go to the "Productivity" one I may not get so many Linux people at once.

My question isn't a technical one. It's more "spiritual".

I want to use Linux but I feel "lost" when I actually have it. Don't get me wrong, it's not about knowledge or anything. I have no problem learning new things.

I just have this feeling every time I wipe out Windows to move to Linux that doesn't go away. Like when you lose someone dear and after years you still feel him/her in your hearth.

I want to move to Linux. Everything I have to do on Windows I can visualize, so that is not an issue. Also, there are huge benefits in moving to Linux for me, as for the work I do it would really help having a Linux Machine to do "dirty work" (grepping/one-liners/programming in a blink/ecc). I am really motivated.

I think about it for all week at work. And I promise myself that in the weekend I'll wipe off Windows to put Linux. But as soon as I do that I feel "empty". Like a part of me being ripped off.

**My question is**: how can I overcome this feeling long enough to get into the habbit of using Linux, so that I can switch operating systems like nothing? I now it sounds silly but I am really in a dead end.

Comment: Trial and error. And read a lot of HOW TO's. Mess around but do make backups. This is not a very good question for askubuntu though. A better place? http://discourse.ubuntu.com/ :-)

Comment: Learning any new Operating System takes a lot of time, believe me. And mastering it, even more. So don't worry, feeling lost doesn't mean you aren't learning or linux is hard, it just happens to be tough in the beginning. Using it regularly will help you learn. However, this question as it is, is very broad to answer and will be closed, so consider narrowing down to something more objective.

Comment: I suggest you to read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Stocholm syndrome xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to Linux need never be traumatic.  There are many ways to 
keep both operating system available until you are comfortable, and
many ways to keep the old OS around "just in case".  Some of the 
approaches are:

1. Put Linux on an external USB stick or disk.  If the external device
   can be put first in the boot order, you can do this with absolutely
   no change at all to the host machine.
2. You can run Linux in a virtual machine
   like VirtualBox under Windows. WUBI used to be used for this, but is
   being pretty much phased out.
3. Dual boot Linux with Windows.  Both operating systems may be put
   on the same disk, and a choice made at boot time through a
   bootloader like grub.
4. You can run Windows in a virtual
   machine under LInux. VMware offers a converter to grab a copy of a
   running Windows machine, and a free  player.  VirtualBox can run the
   Windows off its original filesystem.

You have a step-by-step approach for getting comfortable with Linux, and ways
to keep Windows around until you just don't care about it anymore.

Comment: My side I would prefer swapping 2&3 (VM before making change with grub, plenty of Secure boot problems)